# Ng/Rx for Angular 14

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I have just finished updating my old Angular v8, to Angular 14 (the latest).

I have now noticed the latest Ng/Rx packages, which I have installed are `13.2.0`, however they seem to want Angular 13, i.e. if I do an `npm i` I get

```
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! While resolving: @ngrx/effects@13.2.0
    npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@14.0.2
    npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
    npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^14.0.2" from the root project
    npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"14.0.2" from @angular/animations@14.0.2
    npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
    npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^14.0.2" from the root project
    npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/animations@"14.0.2" from @angular/platform-browser@14.0.2
    npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
    npm ERR!       @angular/platform-browser@"^14.0.2" from the root project
    npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router)
    npm ERR!   12 more (@angular/common, @angular/compiler, @angular/forms, ...)
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"^13.0.0" from @ngrx/effects@13.2.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/@ngrx/effects
    npm ERR!   @ngrx/effects@"^13.2.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@13.3.11
    npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
    npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^13.0.0" from @ngrx/effects@13.2.0
    npm ERR!   node_modules/@ngrx/effects
    npm ERR!     @ngrx/effects@"^13.2.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I don't want to go back to Angular 13 now, is there a way around this (without having to use `--force?`)

Comment: Maybe try `--legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: NgRx has no stable version which officially supports Angular 14 yet, you can either wait or try version 14.0.0-rc.0

Comment: NgRx v14 was released yesterday

Comment: @JSON - yes I saw that.. just one day after I reverted back to Ng13.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting a similar error for the 14.0.2 @ngrx/effects package.  I had to do a two step process

### Step 1

```
ng add @ngrx/store
```

at this point if I ran `npm install` I would get the same error again because the package.json file has been modified.

### Step 2

Update to the latest version of 14 (You may need to increase this to the latest version at the time your reading this.)

```
ng update @ngrx/store@14
```

### Test

Run `npm install` again to make sure the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all possible ways.. but NgRX was not working with Angular 14 . We can however install a retro version of angular and use NgRX. But finally I got a solution:
https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2022/06/angular-14-statemanagement-crud-example-with-rxjs14.html

Comment: Actually it is now, see https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v14 (I have now upgraded to Angular v14 and NgRx 14 and all is good)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is with `npm`

To fix this RUN:

```
npm install -g npm@6
```

Then:

```
npm install
```